# datetime formatting issue in python dictionary

Tags: python, datetime

I have a dictionary that currently has values that are date periods in the format "YY-MMM" (22-Nov). I'm attempting to replace that with an actual date, but running into issues with the formatting. Below is the code I'm using (in a loop), the key-value that results is 'Fiscal Period': datetime.date(2022, 11, 1), and I'm hoping to get 'Fiscal Period': 11/1/2022. Thanks in advance for assistancee

```
row['Fiscal Period'] = datetime.strptime("1-" + row['Fiscal Period'] 
[3:6] + "-" + row['Fiscal Year'], "%d-%b-%Y").date()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

# Sample data for demonstration
row = {'Fiscal Period': '22-Nov', 'Fiscal Year': '2022'}

# Extract month abbreviation (Nov) and construct the date
row['Fiscal Period'] = datetime.strptime("1-" + row['Fiscal Period'][3:6], "%d-%b").date().replace(year=int(row['Fiscal Year']))

# Format the date as desired (MM/DD/YYYY)
formatted_date = row['Fiscal Period'].strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(formatted_date)
```

Output:

```
11/01/2022
```